# What is an example of MissingBackPressure for BehaviourSubject?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an android app using RxJava1.x occasionally throwing `MissingBackPressure` when using `BehaviourSubject`.

It only emit one list contains objects to populate a view.

```
    behaviourSubject.onNext(items);
```

However, It is extremely difficult to reproduce the exception so I'm trying to write a simple test as below.

```
    BehaviorSubject<Object> p = BehaviorSubject.create((Object)1);
    p.test(0).assertFailure(MissingBackpressureException.class);
```

Can someone please help with an example of this kind? thanks.

```
Caused by rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.onNext(SourceFile:160)
   at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(SourceFile:135)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext(SourceFile:253)
   at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(SourceFile:160)
   ...
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(SourceFile:69)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(SourceFile:77)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(SourceFile:41)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(SourceFile:38)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(SourceFile:173)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber$1.request(SourceFile:109)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:211)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:105)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:205)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:205)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:102)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:102)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(SourceFile:205)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(SourceFile:152)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(SourceFile:138)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(SourceFile:1048)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(SourceFile:10256)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(SourceFile:1048)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(SourceFile:10256)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(SourceFile:1048)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(SourceFile:1048)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(SourceFile:10256)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(SourceFile:100)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(SourceFile:230)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(SourceFile:55)
```

Comment: The v1 `BehaviorSubject` ignores backpressure, thus you can only assert that there were no values emitted when using `test(0)`.

Comment: @akarnokd, Hi, thanks. i understand it doesn't support BackPressure, but somehow my crash log is reporting `MissingBackPressure` from `BehaviorSubject.onNext` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.x `BehaviorSubject` ignores backpressure and emits without considering any request amount, thus it won't ever signal `MissingBackpressureException`. If you see such error in your log, that comes from another operator; this is why you should always post failure stacktraces.

I'm not sure why you'd want to unit test the `BehaviorSubject` itself for this exception, but the closest thing that does signal `MissingBackpressureException` is `PublishSubject`:

```
BehaviorSubject<Object> bs = BehaviorSubject.create((Object)1);

PublishSubject<Object> ps = PublishSubject.create();

AssertableSubscriber<Object> as = ps.test(0);

bs.subscribe(ps);

as.assertFailure(MissingBackpressureException.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have attached the crash log.

Comment: As suspected, it is `observeOn`. Use `onBackpressureBuffer`, `onBackpressureDrop` or `onBackpressureLatest` before `observeOn to avoid this error.